# Setting up Eclipse to always include hadoop jar files

Tags: java, eclipse, hadoop

I am trying to create an Eclipse folder(package?) team members can download and when they create new projects, it will automatically add the Hadoop jar files into the classpath, is this possible?

Thanks!

PS. I did ask in the Eclipse forums but there was no response.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a dummy project with complete config and libs. A dev would only have to rename it..

Or if you want to go the maven road, use an archetype.

Comment: I nearly looks like I copied your answer ^^

Comment: That just means, that there is some truth in it. ;)

Answer (score 0):

I have not heard about such a folder / package concept. Why not create a preconfigured empty project with all your dependencies ? You may also create a Maven project to easily manage dependencies.